# Keep variable result during reload/redirect

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

I have a webpage where i upload a csv file that is then imported to a **mysql** database with php. 
I have a mysql query that goes like `"SELECT * FROM wifi"` and then count the lines in the database. Then it should run the import of the csv and make the same query and count the lines again showing me a "before and after" number. This i got working, sort of. 

The issue is, the first query counting the "before" number is in the top of the page and it shows the number nice, when i hit the submit-button it sends my csv into the php inserting it into the databse and redirecting to `"pagehere?success=1"` where it should show me the "after" number. But as the page reloads/redirects, the first query with the "before" number is re-run and shows the "after" number.

 So i have one "before" number, imports csv and page reloads, then i have two "after" numbers. 


How can i keep the "before" number during the redirect of the page?

Code goes like this (i´m still learning, might be something wrong)

```
(THIS CODE IS IN WEBPAGE)
//Count before import
$before = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wifi");
$num_rows_before = mysql_num_rows($before);

(THIS CODE IS WHERE THE FORM UPLOAD FILE TO AFTER SUBMIT-BUTTON)
<?php 

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do {
    if ($data[0]) {
        mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO wifi (bssid, channel, privacy, ciper, auth, power, essid, latitude, longitude, first_seen, last_seen) VALUES
            (
                '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                '".addslashes($data[8])."',
                '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                '".addslashes($data[10])."' 
            )
        ");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,","));

//redirect
header('Location: index.php/upload?success=1'); die;

}

//Count after import
$after = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wifi");
$num_rows_after = mysql_num_rows($after);


//echo stats
echo "Number of rows before - ";
echo "$num_rows_before";
<br>
echo "Number of rows after - ";
echo "$num_rows_after";

//generic success notice
if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<br><b>Result: Your file is imported!</b><br>"; } 

//Close connection to databse
mysql_close($connect) ; 

?>
```

Comment: use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) to retain state between requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the "before" number to the second webpage as an argument. So, change the last line of your code to

```
header('Location: index.php/upload?success=1&before=' . $num_rows_before); die;
```

Comment: `$before` is the mysql query connection. This cannot be passed through the URL. `$num_rows_before` could.

Comment: Yes, and you can acesss the count as `$_POST['before']`

Comment: could i do echo "$_POST['before']"; ?

Comment: When i insert `echo "$_POST['before']";` the page doesn´t load "index.php/upload?success=1&before=295" in the url. Just flash and go back to "index.php/upload"

Comment: I know the "before" value, upload the file and the value is shown in the url. the "after" value is also correct. But i cant seem to echo the "url-value" down to the page again.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my answer - there's an extra `.php`. I've just corrected it. If this doesn't help, please add at least some of index.php to your question.

Comment: Solved it like this.
`//redirect
    header('Location: index.php/upload?success=1&before=' . $num_rows_before); die;
}`

`//Catch argument from url
$arg_before=$_GET['before'];

echo "$arg_before";` 
And now it works. Thaks for the help. Really Awseome :)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out - sorry, all my comments about `$_POST` above should have been `$_GET`. (Blush)

Comment: Another question ;) How could i (in this php) capture the "nicefile.csv" and count the rows in the file? 
I tried something like `$csvlinecount = count(file('$_FILES[csv]'));` without result. 
The reason is i have before and after from the database, but im sorting out duplicate entries. So it would be fun to know if the before number is 100 and after 200, then i know it imported 100. But if i dont know the amount of lines in the csv-file, i dont know how many it skipped during the import.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to keep data between requests

1. Use `session` as Orangepill suggested. For PHP, you can store session in `$_SESSION` if you are using raw PHP
2. Use URL query params. After processing the data, you can set the params for the URL in order to save the last value. `yourdomain.com?previous=somepreviousdata`
3. Use cookies. You can also store the previous data in cookie. If you are using raw PHP without any framework, you can do it by using `setcookie("previous", $data);`